# Usuarios acceden a sesiones de otros usuarios

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, nginx

Buenas noches, les comento mi problema. Tengo una app desarrollada en PHP con Codeigniter corriendo sobre un web hosting en Wiroos. Todo venia funcionando correctamente, pero a medida que pasó el tiempo, la aplicacion fue teniendo mas usuarios los cuales acceden simultaneamente (obviamente) y comenzó a ocurrir el siguiente problema.

Cuando el usuario A se loguea desde la ubicacion A, se genera una sesion A. Si al mismo tiempo el usuario B desde la ubicacion B accede a la aplicacion, automaticamente se le carga la sesion del usuario A en su ubicacion B... como puede ser esto posible?

Les muestro el codigo de mi aplicacion para ver si me pueden ayudar

**Controlador Login**

```
public function index($estadoLogin = 0){

    if($this->session->userdata('estado_sesion'))
    {
        redirect(base_url()."panel");
    }
    $data['estadoLogin'] = $estadoLogin;
    $data['title'] = "Iniciar Sesión - LandingApp";
    $data['bodyClass'] = "external-page sb-l-c sb-r-c";

    $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);        
    $this->load->view('login/loginbox', $data);

}//End method index
```

**Metodo login**

```
    public function ingresar(){
    $correo = $this->security->xss_clean(strip_tags($this->input->post('correo')));
    $pass = md5($this->security->xss_clean(strip_tags($this->input->post('password'))));

    $Usuarios = new Usuario_Model();
    $result = $Usuarios->login($correo, $pass);
    if(count($result)>0){
        foreach($result as $u){
            $this->session->unset_userdata('id');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('mail');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('nombre');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('activo');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('logo_empresa');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('nombre_empresa');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('id_empresa');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('nivel');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('estado_sesion');

            $this->session->set_userdata('id', $u->id);
            $this->session->set_userdata('mail', $u->mail);
            $this->session->set_userdata('nombre', $u->nombre);
            $this->session->set_userdata('activo', $u->activo);
            $this->session->set_userdata('nivel', $u->nivel);
            $this->session->set_userdata('nombre_empresa', $u->nombre_empresa);
            $this->session->set_userdata('id_empresa', $u->id_empresa);
            $this->session->set_userdata('logo_empresa', $u->logo_empresa);
            $this->session->set_userdata('avatar_user', $u->avatar_user);
            $this->session->set_userdata('estado_sesion', TRUE);

            redirect(base_url()."panel");

        }//End foreach


    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('mensaje', 'El usuario o password es incorrecto');
        redirect(base_url()."login/index/1");
        //$this->index(1);
    }//End if
```

**Controlador Panel**

```
public function index(){


    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $id_empresa = $this->session->userdata('id_empresa');

    $data_session['title'] = "Panel General";
    $data_session['opcionMenu'] = "panel";
    $data_session['bodyClass'] = "dashboard-page";

    $data_session = $this->session_data_lib->set_data_session($data_session); //cargo las variables de sesion

    if ($data_session['nivel']==1 || $data_session['nivel']==2){

        $data_counters = $this->counters_lib->get_admin_counters(); //cargo las variables de contadores

    }else{
        $data_counters = $this->counters_lib->get_user_counters(); //cargo las variables de contadores
    }

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data_session);
    $this->load->view('templates/menu_top', $data_session);
    $this->load->view('templates/menu_left', $data_counters);
    if ($data_session['nivel']==0) {
        $this->load->view('panel/panel_user',$data_counters);
    }else{
        $this->load->view('panel/panel_admin',$data_counters);
    }

    $this->load->view('templates/footer',$data_counters);

}//End method index
```

**Session_Data_lib > set_data_session**

```
public function set_data_session($data_session){
$data_lib_session['title'] = $data_session['title'];
$data_lib_session['opcionMenu'] = $data_session['opcionMenu'];
$data_lib_session['bodyClass'] = $data_session['bodyClass'];
$data_lib_session['nombre'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('nombre');
$data_lib_session['userid'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('id');
$data_lib_session['nivel'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('nivel');
$data_lib_session['avatar_user'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('avatar_user');
$data_lib_session['logo_empresa'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('logo_empresa');
$data_lib_session['nombre_empresa'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('nombre_empresa');
$data_lib_session['id_empresa'] = $this->CI->session->userdata('id_empresa');
$data_lib_session['arr_css'] = array("absolute_admin/assets/fonts/iconsweets/iconsweets.css");
$data_lib_session['lastSegs'] = $this->CI->panel_model->get10LastSeg($this->CI->session->userdata('id_empresa'));

return $data_lib_session;
}//End method set_data_session
```

---

Intenté migrando Codeigniter a la version 3.0, y hasta realice la siguiente configuracion en application/config/config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Ya no se que mas probar, tengo la sensacion de que puede ser una configuracion del servidor, pero aun no tuve respuesta del soporte mas que esto:

> Nuestros servidores tienen una capa de micro-cache manejada por nginx que puede haber ocasionado este comportamiento, ahora lo desactivé para tu dominio. Podrías, por favor, probarlo nuevamente?

Evidentemente el problema persiste. No comprendo como puede ser que dos usuarios distintos desde ubicaciones diferentes puedan acceder a la sesion del otro en el momento que ambos estan consultando al servidor. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radicaba en el hosting debido a una configuracion en la capa de micro-cache manejada por nginx. Lo desactivaron en mi dominio y el problema desaparecio.

Tema cerrado, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías publicar el código del `Usuario_model` para ver la comparación de usuario/contraseña? Tal vez la consulta de usuario te devuelva mas de un valor...